# Condition code for featured article content joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, conditional-statements, joomla3.0

in previous versions of joomla the following code worked to enable different content to be presented for the featured article:

```
<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='featured') : ?>
STUFF FOR HOMEPAGE
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if (JRequest::getVar('view')!=='featured') : ?>
STUFF FOR ANY PAGES APART FROM HOMEPAGE
<?php endif; ?>
```

...or something like this anyway. Is there an equivalent function in joomla 3. I have spent a considerable amount of time searching for a solution, however i am not familiar with php code so am unsure as to what exactly i am looking for. As of yet i have not found anything for joomla 3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
<?php if ($input->get('view', '') == 'featured') : ?>
STUFF FOR HOMEPAGE
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ($input->get('view', '') !== 'featured') : ?>
STUFF FOR ANY PAGES APART FROM HOMEPAGE
<?php endif; ?>
```

`JRequest` class is no more supported so use `$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's much appreciated. Unfortunately, when i added this into my index.php file, i got the following: $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/wealthar/public_html/wa/templates/protostar/index.php on line 172

Comment: Does the line $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input; have to be placed at the start of the document? I tried that however it has caused the content "stuff for homepage" to not display at all.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: Let me know, What do you want to do if view is featured? So that I can give you proper solution.

Comment: I need the div that contains the article on the home page to have one particular background, and then on other pages, i need it to have a different background. I'm sure there are different ways to do it, but the way i know is to have <div id="homepage">FEATURED ARTICLE</div> only show up on the home page, and then have <div id="otherpages">OTHER PAGE ARTICLES</div>. Therefore i can style both #homepage and #otherpages differntly to cater for the different background requirements.

Comment: I need the code to hide the divs for the other pages when the featured article is displayed (and vice versa), otherwise due to the <jdoc:include type="component" /> line being used twice (once for featured and then once for the standard articles), the articles will show up twice on any given page.

Comment: Then you should do it by template over-riding. Copy Joomla => components => com_content => views => featured => default.php to Joomla => templates => selectedTemplate => html => com_content => featured => default.php and make required changes.

Comment: Wouldn't have thought of that. Cheers for the pointers. I'll let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: Here's the code from Protostar
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
Then you would say if $view == 'featured'

Answer (score 1):

From the comment i believe you want to style homepage, not featured view, so use this code insteat:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$frontpage = ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault());
if ($frontpage) {
  echo 'This is the front page';
} else {
  echo 'This is NOT front page';
}
```

You can find more info here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_if_the_user_is_viewing_the_front_page